# Date Picker issue , showing element not visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Team I have a DOM like this where the date picker Id is clear but as the attribute readonly="readonly" , on execution its showing as Element not visible. Please help

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? And, please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0):

you can remove readonly attribute using Javascript, find below code it may helps you.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('elementID').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");
```

Comment: Hi Chandra Thanks for ur reply , I tried but its not working , As you see in the html the Id is given clearly but also its showing as element not visible , bcuz the date field is in grey out color.

Comment: I hope you also tried like this, 'WebElement BirthDate=driver.findElement(By.id("Dob"))
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('Dob').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");
  BirthDate.clear();
  BirthDate.sendKeys("12/12/1985");'  I taken birthday as example

Comment: Let me add the code which I given , 
ea.scrollToAnElement(policyTermFromDate);          
((JavascriptExecutor)StepUtil.driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('InsuranceDateFromM').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");
Thread.sleep(2000);  
ea.datePicker(policyTermFromDate,PTFromDate);    
((JavascriptExecutor)StepUtil.driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('txtYearsInBusiness').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");
Thread.sleep(2000);    
    ea.datePicker(dateOfCommOfBusiness,dateOfComBus);

Comment: One more thing is i didnt pass the date through Send keys , I created a separate method for date picker and passing day and that element as parameter into that method.